# React Site Showing on Netlify but Not on GitHub Pages

Tags: reactjs, github-pages, vite

I uploaded my React site to GitHub under the repo jschlte.github.io it displays a blank page with the error of "Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/jsx". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec". But on Netlify the site loads up just fine.

GitHub Pages: https://jschlte.github.io/
Netlify: https://jschlte.netlify.app/

My package.json[image]

My vite.config.js file [image]

My main.jsx file [image]

Answer (score 1):

This github page only host `static` website. If you develop your web based on Reactjs, you need to translate your codes to pure html/css/js by using tool like webpack. In your case, you only need to `npm run build` and `deploy` again to your github repo. Then everything will work.